# how to run exe() from browser

Tags: php, python-2.7

Hello I'm new to both PHP and python but I'm using them both in my graduation project I have an OTP code to generate a random number and send SMS to phone numbers and another code that runs a fingerprint scanner.both are working fine when I use exec() in PHP to run them in cmd but when using browser only the otp code works with the webpage, I've changed the permission of the apache user and gave it root privileges and tried both system() and exec() functions but still nothing shows up when using trying to execute the fingerprint code from browser
I would appreciate any help because I am stuck on this for many hours days now

Answer (score 2):

> I've changed the permission of the apache user and gave it root privileges

OMG no.

If your supervisor (whom is being paid to give you advice) thinks this a good idea, then find another supervisor.

You have not provided nearly enough information to form an opinion on the cause. You need to investigate which file permissions are relevant to the problem - that is Unix filesystem privileges on executables, devices and data files, but you also need to look at any mandatory access control systems which might be in play (SELinux, Apparmor, smack). You should also try running the programs from an interactive shell as the Apache uid. Note that it is usually a good idea to severely restricted the programs the webserver can run and whitelist specific actions for the webserver/webserver uid via sudo.